# Linux Cron: Can I displace the runtime by "x" minutes?

Tags: cron

NOTE: I'm a big newbie when it comes to *nix.

I have a cron configuration that runs several programs. Most of them run once a day, and they're set at different times (2AM, 3AM, 4AM, etc) so they don't run all at the same time.

Now, I have a process that runs every 10 minutes, that always runs really fast (around 6 seconds), and it's getting "overlapped" with the 2AM, 3AM, 4AM, processes.

It's currently configured like this:

*/10 * * * *  /home/blahblah

and it runs at 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 minutes.

Would it be possible to have it run at "not 0", but displaced, for example, 5 minutes?
Thus, it'd run at 5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55 instead.
Something like "*/10+5" if you will.

The idea is to simply avoid this process running at the same time as the ones that run at :00 minutes, and to still have it run approximately every 10 minutes.

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to do this in your crontab:

`5,15,25,35,45,55 * * * * /home/blahblah`

That first part tells it to run at 5,15,...,45,55 minuites every hour of ever day of every month of every year

Answer (score 0):

DUH, just found it...

8,18,28,38,48,58 * * * *  /home/blahblah

Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following line to run every 5,15,25,35,45, and 55th minutes

```
5-55/10 * * * * sh foobar.sh
```

This works Vixie cron which is default cron in most of operating systems.